# Prove limit of the $a^n$ sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to understand and prove the following limit of this sequence 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( a \right)^n = \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  +\infty \  \leftrightarrow \  a>1 \\
                  \ 1 \ \ \ \ \ \leftrightarrow \ a = 1\\
                  \ 0\ \ \ \ \ \leftrightarrow\ -1<a<1 \\
                  \ \nexists  \ \ \ \ \ \leftrightarrow\ a \leq -1
                \end{array}
              \right. $$

I've proved the first one, so when `a > 1`, in this way with **Bernoulli's inequality**:
$(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx \\ 
(1+(a-1))^n \geq 1+n(a-1) \\ 
a^n \geq 1+n(a-1) \\
a^n \geq 1+\infty(a-1) \\
a^n \geq 1+\infty \\
a^n \geq \infty \\$

But I don't know how to proceed with the others cases, can you explain explain step by step, thank a lot!

Comment: Actually the line $a^n \geq 1+\infty(a-1)$ makes little sense. $\infty$ is not number. It only makes sense (among other things) as the result of a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already proved almost correctly that $a>1 \Rightarrow a^n \to +\infty$

Lets use this.

> Let $a \leq -1$
>
> So if $a=-1$ then  $a^n=(-1)^n$ which does not have a limit.
>
> If $a<-1$ then $a=(-1)c$ where $c>1$ thus $a^n=(-1)^nc^n$
>
> So $$\lim_{ n \to +\infty}(-1)^{2n}c^{2n} \to + \infty$$ $$\lim_{ n \to +\infty}(-1)^{2n+1}c^{2n+1} \to - \infty$$
>
> So for two different subsequences we have two different limits thus the limit does not exists.

.

> Now if $a=1$ then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $a^n=1 \to 1$ as $n \to +\infty$

.

> Let $|a|<1$ and $a \neq 0$ then $\frac{1}{|a|}>1$ thus $(\frac{1}{|a|})^n \to +\infty$ thus $|a|^n =\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{|a|})^n} \to \frac{1}{+\infty} = 0$
>
> So $|a^n|= |a|^n \to 0 \Rightarrow a^n \to 0$

.

> If $a=0$ then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}\Rightarrow a^n=0 \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

if $|a|<1$ and $a\ne 0$, then

$$|a^n|=|a|^n=e^{n\ln (|a|)} $$
with $\ln (|a|)<0.$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|a^n|=e^{-\infty}=0$$